# I have notification running. I just need to make it appear at a specific time

Tags: android

I searched all similar questions/answers but I can't get it to work with my code! I can get the notification to appear instantly. However, I need it to appear 24 hrs after the user runs the app.  I am stuck.  I tried using Alarm Manager with no success.  Here is my working code.  Please guide me.  Thanks.

```
public class NotifyNow { 


static void noty(Context context, String message) {

      int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
      long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
      String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
       .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

      Notification notification;
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
      new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);


      NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
      context);
      notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
     .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
     .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
     .setContentText(message).build();

      //notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;


      notification.sound = 
                RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


        notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);






      }
```

I call it from my MainActivity class as follows:

```
NotifyNow.noty(this,"Notification worked");
```

How do I implement the alarm.  I would appreciate detailed answer as I am fairly new to java.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this...

put uppercase notification service

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notifyDetails=new Notification(
                                            R.drawable.icon,contentTitle,System.currentTimeMillis());

    notificationManager .notify(MY_SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

You can achieve this by using [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/tree/master/demo2) library also...

Comment: I am lost on how to use above to make the notification appear 24 hrs after the user runs the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can find Current DateTime using Date APIs, when your app runs by overcreate riding onStart() of Activity.
e.g.

```
currentTime = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
```

> Now, you can add an alarm using AlarmManager API.
>   [AlarmManager Refernce](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)
>
> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, 
>   even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier
>   and much more efficient to use Handler.

Sample Code for Creating an alarm is:

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    currentTime  +
    24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

Please Note: This code is not tested, but just a concept of requisite. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: how would I go about integrating the code with my current code?